# "Easy Custom Labeling" arrows: How do I get them?

Tags: qgis, qgis-1

I have installed the Easy Custom Labeling plugin, but haven't figured out how to make the "Generate lines" function work. When I click on the tool in the toolbar, it opens the dialogue to specify my CRS. Ok, that's done. So having moved a label that was too crowded, how do I make the connector line?

(I'm running QGIS 1.8)

Comment: I was having the same issue TVZ. I think it might be a glitch, because I did not see any arrows, but after changing some settings and changing them back the arrows appeared. In properties>style>simple line, I changed the symbol layer type from "Simple Line" to "Marker Line", and clicked apply. The arrows then appeared as markers. After switching it back to "Simple Line" it worked.

Comment: In my case I don't see the "arrow button" for labels. Therefore I'm completely stuck

Answer (score 1):

you need to first generate a label layer, then move labels by hand, and save the eidts to that layer. 
Then select that label layer (click on it in legend) and click arrow button. 
Arrows will be generated for labels moved by hand only. 
If nothing appeared in your tests, maybe it's because you didn't move labels or didn't save edits. 
The prompt fro CRS is related to your settings in general CRS options. You can hide that prompt if needed by telling QGIS to use project or default CRS..
Régis

Comment: Thanks Regis; sorry if I’m missing something stupid! I generated my label layer (“Label_TVZ GPS points”; See screenshot at
 https://www.dropbox.com/s/ys6ihzbthbkkn1y/Arrows%20screenshot.jpg
I then moved a label; saved my change; then clicked the “Generates lines from objects to labels” tool (6th tool from left, second toolbar row). However, this caused creation of the new layer, “Arrow_Label_TVZ GPS points”. Clicking that button again only caused creation of another copy of that layer!?!? Ok, what idiotic mistake am I making?